# Converting VARBINARY HEX to VARCHAR

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a fun problem,

I have data stored in SQL Server 2008 `VARDATA` column as Hex.

I need to see what this translated to string is.

I have tried `CONVERT(VarChar(MAX), VARDATA, 2)` and it returns a Varchar value of the hex exactly the same as it is in the `VARDATA`.

If I put the value that is in my `VARDATA` into an online converter I get the exact value I expect back.

Any help would be appreciated.

Details.

Example of the Hex is

```
0x003200300031003400300037003200340030003000300035003600380038003300300039
```

It should work out to.

```
201407240005688309
```

**EDIT:** some additional information. This data starts out in ORACLE it is in a `RAW` type column.

We bring the data to SQL Server 2008 via Linked Servers using the below open query.

```
Select TABNAME, VARKEY, DATALN, VARDATA 
from sapsr3.KAPOL
```

When I use the suggested function on this SQL Server 2008 table below.

```
Select CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),VARDATA) 
from KAPOL
```

I get these symbols:

```
㈀　　㄀　㄀　㄀　　　　　　㜀㜀㠀㠀
```

If I do the conversion of HEX in Oracle first and then try and bring it over I get an empty column.

```
Select TABNAME, VARKEY, DATALN, utl_raw.cast_to_nvarchar2(hextoraw(VARDATA)) VARDATA 
from sapsr3.KAPOL
```

Lastly, in the first instance with no conversion in the oracle table the data type for the column `VARDATA` is `VARBINARY`

When I try the conversion in Oracle first is `NVARCHAR`

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a distinction between `varchar` and `nvarchar`. There is a big difference. If I try to create `varbinary` from your "should work out to" value:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(64), '201407240005688309')
```

I get this value, which looks *kind* of like the value you're converting, but not quite:

```
0x323031343037323430303035363838333039
```

So now if I change the input to be `nvarchar`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(64), N'201407240005688309')
```

Now I do get the value you wanted:

```
0x3200300031003400300037003200340030003000300035003600380038003300
```

So if I take that value and try to convert it to `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`, we're back where we started:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),
  0x3200300031003400300037003200340030003000300035003600380038003300300039)
```

Result:

```
201407240005688309
```

The online converter you're using must be using Unicode behind the scenes. You need to do that, too.

Comment: Ok, so I was on the right track, thanks so much for the info.  When I use the value directly from the DB I get this ㈀　㄀㐀　㜀㈀㐀　　　㔀㘀㠀㠀

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),VARDATA),VARDATA was used for the above

Comment: Ok, so the data was original from Oracle, I need to do the hex conversion in that db first.

Comment: What does "stored as hex" mean? What is the actual data type, and what is the exact insert/update statement that put it there? What is the exact statement that leads to all those Japanese characters?

Comment: The data is originaly stored in oracle in a RAW field as Hex code. We bring it into SQL2008 via a linked server and openquery

Comment: What is the data type in SQL Server? It's in a table, right? Can you check the data type of the column?

Comment: VARBINARY, sorry forgot to post that part in my last comment.

Comment: Something is messing up your varbinary value. It starts with `0x003200...` but it should be `0x3200...`

Comment: IN oracle it's stored that way, it does not have a 0x it has a 00, I wonder if that has something to do with it.

Comment: I don't know anything about how Oracle handles binary conversions. But if you want SQL Server to correctly translate a binary value to `201407240005688309`, you need to make sure you're starting with the right binary value.

Comment: Thank you for your Help Aaron, you led me to the eventual solution.